# Query Linq to Sql Entity Framework c#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have this query in SQL, but I do not know how can I do it in Linq

This is the query

```
SELECT 
    GroupName, GroupsId 
FROM 
    Groups 
WHERE 
    GroupsId NOT IN (SELECT Groups.GroupsId 
                     FROM AssignGroups 
                     JOIN Groups ON AssignGroups.GroupsId = Groups.GroupsID 
                                 AND AssignGroups.UsersId = 1) 
ORDER BY 
    GroupName
```

I'm using EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can optimize your query:

```
SELECT
  g.GroupName
, g.GroupsId
FROM Groups g
LEFT JOIN AssignGroups ag
       ON g.GroupsId = ag.GroupsId
      AND ag.UsersId = 1
WHERE ag.GroupsId IS NULL
ORDER BY g.GroupName
```

2) Your linq query:

```
from g in context.Groups
join ag in context.AssignGroups
on new {g.GroupsId, UsersId = 1} equals new {ag.GroupsId, ag.UsersId} into ags
from ag in ags.DefaultIfEmpty()
where ag.GroupsId == null
orderby g.GroupName
select new {g.GroupName, g.GroupsId}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = from group in Groups
             let validGroups = from aGroup in AssignGroups 
                               from vGroup in Groups 
                               where aGroup.GroupsId == vGroup.GroupsID  &&
                               vGroup.UserId == 1
                               select vGroup.GroupsID
             where validGroups.Contains(group.GroupID)
             orderby group.GroupName
             select group;
```

The key here is the "let" clausule which creates a subquery, it's an IQueryable< T >, so it can be used with a "Contains" clausule (which in the end will be translated to an "IN()" clausule).

Comment: It would be nice if you added explanation for him.